# Searching for first index in an array of arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data as such:

```
[['Account 1', 122.00], ['Account 2', 342.33], ['Account 3', 103.32]]
```

I wish to be able to check to see if a string exists in any of the first indexes of the arrays and find it's index in the overall array. In other words:

```
index = find(arr, 'Account 2') // This would return 1
```

Does JS already have something internal that can do this?

Comment: For any such collections / arrays functions, use the beautiful and elegant underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/). I am sure you can find the functions you need in this library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES6 there will be a [`findIndex` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which will do just what you want here. You'll probably need to [shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill), though.

```
var arr = [['Account 1', 122.00], ['Account 2', 342.33], ['Account 3', 103.32]]
var index = arr.findIndex(function(item) { return item[0] == 'Account 2'; }) // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's something built in, but you could always run a simple loop

```
var index;
for(var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++)
    if(yourArray[i][0] == 'Account 2')
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
```

This will make the index variable the index that you're looking for. You can make this a function in your own code to avoid repeating code.

Comment: `int` is no javascript?

Comment: Good catch. Been coding in c# and vba all day. Edited.

Comment: Yes, even if I know he surely doesn't have the same account twice.

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your needs:

```
var arr = [['Account 1', 122.00], ['Account 2', 342.33], ['Account 3', 103.32]];

function find( data, term ){
    ret = null;
    data.forEach(function(item, index){
        if (item[0] === term)
            ret = index;
    });
    return ret;
};
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eguj3d5e/

Comment: Yours has the same problem mine did. If the term you're searching for is in the array twice, it returns the index of it's last instance. http://jsfiddle.net/eguj3d5e/1/

Answer (score 0):

Works like this...

```
var arr = [['Account 1', 122.00], ['Account 2', 342.33], ['Account 3', 103.32]];

var find = function(array, string) {
    var ret;
    array.forEach(function(arr, index) {
        if(arr[0] === string){
            ret = index;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}

find(arr, 'Account 2');
```

Comment: Your `find` function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: true wrote it too fast

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

See [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/h0udvty5/)

```
var myarr = [['Account 1', 122.00], ['Account 2', 342.33], ['Account 3', 103.32]];
var result = jinqJs().from(myarr).where(function(row){return row[0] === 'Account 2'}).select();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
index = indexOf(arr, 'Account 2')
```